Can't split text using IFS=$'\n', and answers don't respond
I'm learning bash-scripting, and am in the process of building a "quiz app", which is supposed to pick a random question from a json file of questions, display the possible answers, let me pick an answer from 1 to 4 and write if I've chosen correctly.
As far as I can tell, I've followed every step the teacher made, but what I'm getting is:
QUESTION
1) ANSWER 1
ANSWER 2
ANSWER 3
ANSWER 4

Also, pressing any number, which is supposed to send the corresponding answer to verify if it's correct, always gives me the message that this is not correct.
Here is my code:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
 
load_question() {
    local contents
    local qtotal
    local qrandom
    local question
 
    contents=$(cat ./questions.json)
    qtotal=$(echo "${contents}" | jq '.results | length')
    (( qrandom = RANDOM % qtotal ))
    question=$(echo "${contents}" | jq ".results[${qrandom}]")
    echo "${question}" | jq -r ".question"
    echo "${question}" | jq -r ".correct_answer"
    echo "${question}" | jq -r ".incorrect_answers[0]"
    echo "${question}" | jq -r ".incorrect_answers[1]"
    echo "${question}" | jq -r ".incorrect_answers[2]"
}
 
ask_question() {   
    local question="$1"
    local correct_answer="$2"
    local incorrect_answer_0="$3"
    local incorrect_answer_1="$4"
    local incorrect_answer_2="$5"
    local answers
 
    answers=$(echo -e "${correct_answer}\n${incorrect_answer_0}\n${incorrect_answer_1}\n${incorrect_answer_2}" | sort -R)
 
    echo "${question}"
    IFS=$'\n'
    select answer in "${answers}"; do
        if [[ "${answer}" == "${correct_answer}" ]]; then
            echo "You got it!"
            return 0
        
        else
            echo "This ain't it, chief!"
            return 1
        fi
    done
 
    
}
 
main() {
    local question
    local correct_answer
    local incorrect_answer_0
    local incorrect_answer_1
    local incorrect_answer_2
    
    {
        read -r question
        read -r correct_answer
        read -r incorrect_answer_0
        read -r incorrect_answer_1
        read -r incorrect_answer_2
    } < <(load_question)
 
    ask_question "${question}"\
                 "${correct_answer}"\
                 "${incorrect_answer_0}"\
                 "${incorrect_answer_1}"\
                 "${incorrect_answer_2}"
}
 
 
 
main "$@"

Tried to copy the teacher's final code.

Does your file have Windows/DOS newlines? Why do you redefine IFS? Quoting parameter expansions will not perform word splitting. And if your questions are single lines (can be obtained with e.g. jq -c), then jq -c '.results[]' | shuf -n1 might be a lot simpler (and more random) than using $((RANDOM%length)).

Also, have you run your script through shellcheck already?

Separately, echo -e is bad form. printf '%s\n' "first line" "second line" is much more reliable -- even if one of the lines itself contains a backslash-escape sequence that data will be understood to be literal, and you don't need to worry about runtime configuration (like xpg_echo) changing the command's behavior in a way that breaks your code.

I think the problems is this lines:
    select answer in "${answers}"; do

You only have one answer which is the concatenation of all responses (it can be seen in your output: there is only a 1) but no 2)
I believe the most elegant fix would be to change $answers into an array:
    readarray -d '' answers < <(printf '%s\0' "${correct_answer}" "${incorrect_answer_0}" "${incorrect_answer_1}" "${incorrect_answer_2}" | sort -R --zero-terminated)

    # NOTE: there is no need to change IFS here!

    echo "${question}"
    select answer in "${answers[@]}"; do

